# dmesg log messages meaning

Tags: networking, wireless, dmesg

I need to understand the meaning of the following messages I get when I run dmesg in order to investigate why a certain AP is having problems connecting specifically with my laptop.

Here are the messages I'm getting that I find suspicious and I need to understand

```
Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised x
deauthenticating from x by local choice (reason=3)
deauthenticating from x by local choice (reason=2)
```

**Update** with full logs

```
[10421.804625] wlan1: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[10421.808067] wlan1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[10421.832374] wlan1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
[10421.834345] wlan1: authenticated
[10421.836063] wlan1: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[10421.873549] wlan1: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
[10421.878351] wlan1: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[10421.884235] wlan1: associated
[10421.884384] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: EG
[10421.890886] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: EG
[10421.890896] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[10421.890901] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[10421.890906] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[10421.890910] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[10505.540819] wlan1: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Reason: 3)
[10505.571989] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[10505.577928] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[10505.577933] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[10505.577936] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10505.577938] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10505.577940] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10505.577943] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10505.577945] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10508.712246] wlan1: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[10508.715881] wlan1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[10508.740321] wlan1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
[10508.742317] wlan1: authenticated
[10508.743270] wlan1: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[10508.783452] wlan1: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
[10508.787617] wlan1: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[10508.793260] wlan1: associated
[10508.793434] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: EG
[10508.800528] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: EG
[10508.800537] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[10508.800542] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[10508.800547] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[10508.800551] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
```

Answer (score 0):

kernel message "Limiting TX power to %d (%d - %d) dBm as advertised by ..." is from ieee80211_handle_pwr_constr() in net/mac80211/mlme.c.  The comment by the decision to limit the TX power states:

"If we have both 802.11h and Cisco DTPC, apply both limits by picking the smallest of the two power levels advertised."

DTPC is a dynamic mechanism where a wireless Access Point can instruct a wireless client to change its radio transmit power setting so that it is optimal for the distance that the client is operating from the AP.  The advantage of DTPC is to tweak the client to AP power level while simultaneously reducing the amount of co-channel interference created by the wireless client.

The "deauthenticating from ... by local choice " message is also from the same source code, from ieee80211_mgd_deauth().

Reason code 2: WLAN_REASON_PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID

Reason code 3: WLAN_REASON_DEAUTH_LEAVING

I'm not entirely sure what that means in your case. It seems that the client has had it's power dropped by the DTPC and then deauthenticates and perhaps this is the reason why your association with the AP is not working reliably.

Maybe disabling DTPC in your access point could help.

Comment: Do you have DTPC enabled on the Access Point? If so, can it be disabled to see if it improves things?